# Clear out and restore fixture data using Grails/GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a need to reset GORM fixture data (H2) on a controller request. So I created the following controller...

```
def dataSource
FixtureLoader fixtureLoader
def index() {
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.execute("DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES")
    sql.close()
    fixtureLoader.load('f1','f2','f3')
}
```

I would expect this to clear out the DB, however, I still get the following error

> [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver]
>   NonUniqueObjectException occurred when processing request: [GET] 
>   a different object with the same identifier value was already
>   associated with the session: [*]. Stacktrace follows:
>   org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session: [*]

another weird thing is if I go into the dbconsole and blow everything away using the 'DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES' command and when I go the the controller I get the same error. Even though I can confirm they are wiped out of the DB.

**UPDATE**

So I have tried a few things...

1.) 'DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES' seems to work as expected in dbconsole. but the code

```
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.execute("DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES")
    sql.close()
```

Seems to not have the same effect.

2.) I have added the following lines

```
def sessionFactory
...
sql.close()
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush() //This one  
fixtureLoader.load('f1','f2','f3')
```

Then I go and delete in DB console (since the SQL seems to be failing), then run. However, when I run the function again I still see the fixtures.

Comment: Sounds as if the hibernate session/cache hasn't been flushed/cleared and thus thinks there is a duplicate even if you have changed the datastore. You might have luck disabling hibernate cache in the test environment.

Comment: Thats what I thought close did, I also tried sql.execute("DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES")

Comment: Please see my update, am I failing to clear the cache properly?

Comment: You are missing a fundamental piece of the puzzle here. Even if you execute a SQL statement to "blow away" all your data, Hibernate still exists in your typical Grails application, and by default it has it's own cache that is independent of your database. When you alter the database without going through Hibernate you are circumventing Hibernate's ability to manage the cache, thus ending up in this situation where while the data doesn't exist Hibernate still thinks it does. Look into clearing the Hibernate cahce, or disabling it (if that makes sense to your app), or use Hibernate to nuke.

Comment: `session.flush()` isn't going to do anything since you aren't using the Hibernate session to effect your database. So, no that's not correct.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to clear it the session answer was a byproduct of some quick googling but I think you are right doesn't make sense. I tried 'sessionFactory.queryCache.clear()' because that seemed to make a little more sense but didn't work either. I get the issue now but also the SQL doesn't seem to work I have to use dbconsole to actually clear the values but I suppose that is another issue

Comment: Looks like I will also have to recreate the schema otherwise I get table not found when trying to reload the fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I basically did the same as the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628929/grails-recreate-database-schema-for-integration-test)...

In my Bootstrap I create the tmp file and then when the controller is called I run it as a script and everything gets reset. I did also have to make sure that caching was removed per the comment.